# Creating an array from a bracketed and comma delimited key value of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a key value that returns more than one item and I'm struggling to get the data out like I need.

**Post data array**

```
Array
(
    [myproducts] => Array
        (
            [0] => ["Product One","Product Two"]
            [1] => USD
            [2] => 19.20
        )
)
```

**What I've tried:**

```
// Get product array as list

$prod_arr = $_POST['myproducts'];
$products = array ($prod_arr['0'],$prod_arr['1'],$prod_arr['2']);

$arrlength = count($products);
    for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
        echo '<ul>';
        echo '<li>'.$products[$x].'</li>';
        echo '</ul>';
    }
```

*This gives me:*

```
["Product One","Product Two"]
USD
19.20
```

*If I explode the the first key:*

```
print_r (explode('","',$prod_arr["0"]));

Array 
( 
    [0] => ["Product One) 
    [1] => Product Two"] 
    )
```

I want to get the products from the array, but it's adding the `["` and `"]` making it difficult if not impossible in my situation to use the first and last value within the array.

**How can I break `[myproducts][0]` into it's own array?**

Comment: Tip: `print_r(json_decode('["Product One","Product Two"]'));`

Comment: print_r($prod_arr[0][0]) should give you "Product One"

Comment: `print_r(json_decode($prod_arr[0]));` get's the array but I cannot access the value as `[0][0]` and `[0][1]`. BUT - I got this. I'll post the answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array in question needs to be decoded using `json_decode()`.

```
$list_items = json_decode($prod_arr[0]);
```

To access the values loop through each key. I've included a line break.

```
$arrlength = count($list_items);
    for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
        echo $list_items[$x];
        echo '<br>';
    }
```

The output:

```
Product One
Product Two
```